# primefaces or JSF inputText do not refresh its value on form load

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces dialog form wich is loaded upon a datatable row selection:

```
<p:dialog id="dialog-editfield" header="Edit Form Field"
        widgetVar="dlg8" dynamic="true" modal="true" resizable="false">
    <p:panelGrid id="displaySingleFormField" columns="2">

        <h:outputText value="Id:" style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:10px" />
        <h:outputText value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.selectedCRFormField.fieldId}" />

        <h:outputText value="Field Name:" style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:10px" />                       
        <h:outputText value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.selectedCRFormField.fieldName}" />

        <h:outputText value="Associated Feature:" style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:10px" />                       
        <p:selectOneMenu id="imtype2" value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.newOptionVariable}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{reportConfiguratorBean.selectedVariable}" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.variables}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <h:outputText value="Field Label:" style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:10px" />                      
        <p:inputText value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.selectedCRFormField.fieldLabel}" />

        ...
        ...
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

The ajax components which sets the corresponding objects in the backbean and the command button that load the dialog are:

```
<p:panelGrid> ...
    <p:panel> ...
        <p:dataTable id="formfields" var="cRFormField" ... selection="#{reportConfiguratorBean.selectedCRFormField}"> ...
        ...
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{reportConfiguratorBean.setSelectedFieldRow}"/>
        ....
            <p:commandButton id="editCommand" oncomplete="dlg8.show()" value="Edit" update=":report-configurator:displaySingleFormField"/>
```

The backbean code works fine and each time a row is selected on the datatable it reads/sets the correct data from the database:

```
public void setSelectedFieldRow() {
    Long ffVirtualId = selectedCRFormField.getFieldId();
    virtualFieldId = selectedCRFormField.getFieldId().toString();   
    this.selectedCRFormField.setFieldId(ffVirtualId);
    this.setSelectedCRFormField(selectedCRFormField);
    ...
}
```

Everything on the dialog form is LOADED in the right way the first time that it is called. In the subsequent dialog form calls, everything is also populated in the right way except the "inputText" component which holds the value populated in the first call.

However i have checked and its variable 'selectedCRFormField.fieldLabel' holds the right value.

Also if i change inputText to h:outputText the right (new) value is shown.

How could i force  component to refresh its value? Is it a primefaces bug?

Comment: try to use `h:panelGrid` inside dialog ... will work..

Comment: altered <p:panelGrid> to <h:panelGrid> but no luck. The same behavior still occurs